# Jquery to dynamically create DropDown list in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I want to dynamically generate drop down list in a table, I am able to do the same for text box couldn't do drop down list, throwing some syntax error. Please suggest if there is any alternate way to do the same.

```
enter code here
```

document.getElementById("testtId").addEventListener("click", AddNewFCM, false);

```
    function AddNewFCM() {

        alert('FCM Clicked');
        debugger;
        var ID = $("#tblFCMOperation tbody tr").length;
        if (ID.length != 3) {
            var cnt = $('#tblFCMOperation tbody tr').length;
            var newRow = $('<tr id="trFCMOperation_' + cnt + '" class="trFCMOperation">');

            var cols = "";
            cols += '<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mainTechno.TechnoDesignation, new { @class = "form-control textInput", maxlength = "30", })</td>';
            cols += '<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.mainTecho.TechnoDescription, new SelectList(Model.MainTechnoList, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form_control_70 ddlmargin", @id = "ddlCommodityKeywords", @data_validetta = "required", @data_vd_message_required = "Please select commodity keyword!!" })</td>';
            cols += '<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ECRInput.ProductionPlant, new SelectList(Model.ProductionPlantList, "Id", "Name"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form_control_70 ddlmargin", @id = "ddlProductionPlant", @data_validetta = "required", @data_vd_message_required = "Please select production plant!!" })</td>';
            cols += '<td class="font14">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mainTechno.TechnoDesignation, new { @class = "form-control decimal readonly", @readonly = "readonly", @id = "txtLineIPT" })</td>';
            cols += '<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ECRInput.TEInfoStatus, new SelectList(Model.TEInfoStatusList, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form_control_70 ddlmargin", @id = "ddlTEInfoStatus" })</td>';
            cols += '<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IPTRoleManager.Name, new SelectList(Model.IPTRoleManagerList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form_control_70 ddlmargin", @id = "ddlRoleManager" })</td>';
            cols += '<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mainTechno.TechnoDesignation, new { @class = "form-control textInput readonly" })</td>';
            newRow.append(cols);

            $("#tblFCMOperation").append(newRow);
        };
    }
```

Comment: Macha please add the error you are getting.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, if I understand your post correctly, all you need to do is create a "select" node and append it to the location in the DOM where you want it, you can use standard document methods for this.

Comment: I don't think appending @Html.DropDownList is going to work in javascript. that is razor syntax.  either create a select element with html or do this in razor not javascript

Comment: You're missing the ending single quote and semi-colon on the line highlighted as your error - you can't have newlines in script like in server side strings. That said, this isn't really a great idea, you're mixing script and razor like this will prevent you from creating script files and bundling them. A better solution is a template markup div that you can clone and resuse, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You just need to remove new line from html String.

```js
    (function () {

        $("#testTBL tbody").append('<td><select><option>test11</option><option>test12</option></select></td>' +
            '<td><select><option>test21</option> <option>test22</option></select></td>'+
            '<td>' + '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DropDownList("test", new SelectList(items, "ID", "Name")).ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")))' +'</td>'
        );

    })();
```